# Call function before render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to replace a set of div each time I receive an ajax request (the website I am working on is full ajax...). For example, it could be checking the number of messages in an inbox, or displaying user statistics...

The thing is I don't wan't to repeat this call to my rendering function many times in my code.

I tried to call my function in before_filter, but since I call render :update, it doesn't work the second time.

I tried to create my own function render_page in application_controller :

```
def render_page
  render :update do |page|
    yield(page)
    # page.replace_html :div, ...
  end
end
```

But somehow the context seem to be lost : when i call render_page on a controller's function, I can't access helper functions...

Thanks !

Comment: Not an answer, but if you want to access helpers in controllers, you have to include them: `include RoutesHelper`. edit: but are you sure this should be called in your controller actions? I thought page.replace_html should be called in your .js.erb files...

Comment: technically it works but I know it is not good for the MVC organization... But the question remains ; is it possible to execute a same portion of code at the end of each .js.erb file, without any repetition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it !

I dug a little into the ruby on rails documentation to find out how the render :update function works.

First, I saw that render :update was simply calling update_page by sending the code block...

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#method-i-update_page

And this function is calling the constructor of JavaScriptGenerator by sending view_context (which is simply the instance of ActionView::Base).

```
JavaScriptGenerator.new(view_context, &block).to_s.html_safe
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/new/class

And in the constructor of JavaScriptGenerator, we can observe

```
def initialize(context, &block) #:nodoc:
  @context, @lines = context, []
  include_helpers_from_context
  @context.with_output_buffer(@lines) do
    @context.instance_exec(self, &block)
  end
end
```

instance_exec is a ruby function that allows to call a block within a context... That was exactly what I needed.

So, **the solution** (or at least one working solution...) is to define render_page in application_controller :

```
def render_page(&block)
  render :update do |page|
    page << 'console.log("before_code");'
    self.instance_exec(page, &block)
    page << 'console.log("after_code");'
  end
end
```

This way, instead of calling in my controllers

```
render :update do |page|
  page.replace_html ...
  helper_functions...
end
```

I call

```
render_page do |page|
  page.replace_html ...
  helper_functions...
end
```

And I am still allowed to call my helper functions (since the context has been passed)...